React application working perfectly fine. But stopped working after restarting laptop
I built a website using React, Node.js, MongoDB, Tailwind. Everything was running fine. I restarted my laptop and when I un npm start, it just says "Server running on HTTP://localhost:5002" and "connected to MongoDB", but the application never starts on localhost:3000.
I have been trying for hours to figure out whats going on but I just can't. I don't have any errors either because the code works fine like I said. Any help please!

Are you in your frontend directory when you run npm start?

It's unknown what your project looks like and t's unclear what you did to make a server start at  localhost:3000 . See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If there are two different projects for front and backend, you're supposed to start 2 different servers

To resolve your issue, you can go through this:

Try to delete node_moudles folder, and then run npm install in your project terminal. It will reinstall your dependencies of the project.

Try to use other browesers or clear the cache of your current browser.


Hope it helps you!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
